# How can update a form without uploading file

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado

i want to update a a form with textboxs and file but when i try to update i must update the file too i want if i don't chose the file i could update that's in asp.net

```
 FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.FileName);
 byte[] DocumentContent = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
 string name = fi.Name;
 string extn = fi.Extension;
 using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@" server = DESKTOP-IJCGFFC ; initial catalog = gaf_application ; integrated security =true"))
  {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ModifierFournisseur", cn);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@nom", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentDoc", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = DocumentContent
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@extDoc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = extn;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ref_fourn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@Adress", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@Article_rat", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@Prix_achat", SqlDbType.Float).Value = TextBox4.Text;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@date_fac", SqlDbType.Date).Value = TextBox5.Text;
      cn.Open();

      lblmsg.Visible = true;
      lblmsg.Text = "la modification bien fait!";

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
      TextBox2.Text = "";
      TextBox3.Text = "";
      TextBox4.Text = "";
      TextBox5.Text = "";
  }
```

i can update a the file

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do.

```
string name = string.Empty;
string extn = string.Empty;

if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.FileName);
    byte[] DocumentContent = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
    name = fi.Name;
    extn = fi.Extension;      
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine actually. +1 ... although I'd always check `FileUpload.HasFile` because if you're running that code without it, you're going to get an ArgumentNullException or something when the rest of the code tries to upload a file that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Just add a checkbox to your form and then upload (or don't) based on the Checked value of the checkbox:

```html
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkUpload" Text="Upload File" />
```

```c#
if (chkUpload.Checked)
{
    // The checkbox was checked, so upload the file
}

// Update the database regardless of whether or not the checkbox was checked.
```